# Ruby - How to use different fonts in Prawn?

Tags: ruby, pdf, prawn

I have a small Ruby program where I'm printing some text out to a PDF using Prawn, but a small portion of the text is non-English characters. (Some of that text is Chinese, some is Greek, etc.). When I run my program, I of course get an error saying `Your document includes text that's not compatible with the Windows-1252 character set. (Prawn::Errors::IncompatibleStringEncoding)
If you need full UTF-8 support, use TTF fonts instead of PDF's built-in fonts`. I know that I need to use a TTF font, but how do I even go about that? Do I need to install it from online? If so, where would I save it to? I know that's probably a dumb question but I'm new to Ruby and Prawn. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

ttf is a common format, you can download fonts at [Google font](https://www.google.com/fonts) for instance, put the font in some directory in your project for instance under `/assets/fonts/`

You can then define a new font family like so:

```
Prawn::Document.generate("output.pdf") do
  font_families.update("Arial" => {
    :normal => "/assets/fonts/Arial.ttf",
    :italic => "/assets/fonts/Arial Italic.ttf",
  })
  font "Arial"
end
```

You can then use the font throughout your document.

Comment: In what file should I insert this code ? Also I couldn't find Arial.ttf on Google fonts ?... Any ideas are appreciated ?

Comment: Can I do the same thing on Prawn::Document.new or only on generate?

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty work-around to prevent this error is to encode your text to windows-1252 before writing it to the pdf file.

```
text = text.encode("Windows-1252", invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '')
```

A drawback to this approach is that, if the character you are converting is invalid or undefined in Windows-1252 encoding, it will be replaced by an empty string `''`
Depending on your original text, this solution may work fine, or you may end up missing a few characters in your PDF.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using plain `Ruby` you could try this way:

```
require 'prawn'

Prawn::Document.generate("my_text.pdf") do

  font('Helvetica', size: 50) do
    formatted_text_box(
      [{text: 'Whatever text you need to print'}],
      at: [0, bounds.top],
      width: 100,
      height: 50,
      overflow: :shrink_to_fit,
      disable_wrap_by_char: true  # <---- newly added in 1.2
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: PDF files don't recognize multibyte fonts. They have a character map that maps each byte value to a font glyph (not an ascii table)... so this solution might produce undefined data in the PDF.

Comment: - might work great on your machine and break on another, as it doesn't comply with the PDF standard. Using and mapping a font to the actual data is the way to go. I'm surprised that you tested it with a multi-byte character string, such as Chinese, and that it worked.